# Getting spreadsheets to autopopulate tables?

Tags: arcgis-online, table, arcgis-local-government, spreadsheet

I am working on the Arcgis local government solutions Election Results web app and hosting it out to arcgis online organization. After looking at the spreadsheets, the tables and related feature classes in their solution that you download, I understand everything but how the spreadsheets populate the tables. The spreadsheets have fields for each candidate in a precinct so candidate one, candidate two are separate fields. The precincts records do not repeat. The Tables have precinct records that do repeat, showing the candidates as a list compared to in separate fields like the spreadsheets. The feature classes are related to the tables, and the tables are auto populated by the spreadsheets. I just want to know how to make this work. It seems logical that you wouldn't update the tables independently of the spreadsheets, it seems more likely that you update the spreadsheet and that populates that tables.

How do the individual precinct records in the spreadsheets become multiple precinct records in the tables?

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding correctly, but it sounds like it's reading the precinct column and appending the candidate names based on where they fall in the row ie. PrecinctCol / Name1Col / Name2Col. So you could read each row by precinctcol, and if multiple candidates are found in the row (since precinct is not repeated in the sheet), append it to a table and write the precinct in subsequent cells. I think is what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks for your response - I think you're right. The script must grab the candidate and add a precinct Id row to the geodatabase table from the spreadsheet as it's updated. I appreciate your insight :)